# Create Map<String, List<Object>> where the elements of the lists are sorted, using Stream API

Tags: java, java-8, functional-programming, java-stream

I have any `ArrayList` of "Monitor" objects. Each object has two fields, "brand::String", and "price::BigDecimal". I am using the following Stream, to taxinomize the Monitor objects into a `HashMap<String, List<Monitor>>`, where `key` is the name (so monitors with the same name end up in the same list:

```
Map<String, List<Monitor>> monitorsByNameMap =
    monitors.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Monitor::getName));
```

I would like each `List<Monitor>` in the `HashMap` to be sorted based on the `price` of each `Monitor` object - preferably in ascending order. I was wondering if that can be achieved by adding to the above expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `collectingAndThen` after grouping by `name`

```
Map<String, List<Monitor>> monitorsByNameMap = monitors.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Monitor::getName,
                        Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(),
                              l -> l.stream()
                                       .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Monitor::getPrice))
                                       .collect(Collectors.toList())
                            ))
                    );
```